# How to grab InfoPath form's FormState contents from the document library?

Tags: 2010, development, infopath, document-library

Is there a way to grab the contents of an InfoPath's FormState object? I have access to the SPListItem in the document library it resides in, the xml of the item, the document library it lives in, but I can't seem to access the key/values of the FormState.

E.g. In the code behind of my InfoPath form I have: `FormState.Add("RequestName", "Changed");`

I would like to grab that key value pair, but don't know if I can access it from the document library item. FormState is a XmlFormHostItem.

In the code behind of the InfoPath form, I added a few key/values pairs to the FormState object and I want to read those key values from a document library event receiver. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Why do you put something you want to get externally into Infopath form code-behind (basically internal) variables?  FormState variables are used to maintain the values in Infopath browser forms between postbacks.

If you need to grab the values from Infopath form externally, like in Sharepoint document library, then the most simple way is to create form template's special data fields for putting/getting values both in code-behind and outside  and promote those fields during publishing.      Hide them if you do not want to show them in document library.

Comment: I inherited some forms that store a bunch of information in the FormState and I am trying to consolidate a bunch of that code in some document library event receivers. I was thinking of either storing that info in the xml of the form or, like you suggested, in a field and publish those fields.